# Using [Authorize] makes my app get stuck on an infinite login redirection loop

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently using ASP.NET Core MVC to build my web application. I created my own authentication with claims and it works fine; the problem is when the user is not actually meeting the authentication parameters, they get redirected to the login page. However, the page keeps getting redirected to for some reason, so the user can't even input his credentials.

Here's my `Startup.cs` code:

```cs
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public Startup(IConfiguration config)
{
    _config = config;         
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
        
    services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuth")
            .AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/404.html";
            });
    
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if(env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Here's my `Program.cs` code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .Build();
          
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuth").AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error/404.html");
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnSigningIn = async context =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key"));
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
            context.CookieOptions.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            context.CookieOptions.Secure = true;
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/404.html");

app.Run();
```

I am using the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on my login page, but its still not working. Any idea's on why I'm facing this issue ?

Comment: It's weird that you have `Startup.cs` but your `Program.cs` never calls it. `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are never called. Also you have duplicate code in `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs`. `Startup.cs` is removed from new ASP.NET Core templates. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below, I think the issue cause by [middleware order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75913768/using-authorize-makes-my-app-get-stuck-on-an-infinite-login-redirection-loop).

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
// Correct order
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/404.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work...the same error occurs again

Comment: @YanSoo I have reviewed your code, why you have Startup.cs and Program.cs file, and the code inside Startup.cs never called in Program.cs ?  Could you tell us which doc you referred ?

Comment: I was just following a video tutorial as I remember, I wasn't referring a doc

Comment: @YanSoo You also can share with me. I want check the whole project, not yours. Because your project might have some sensitive info.

Comment: what do you want me to share ? My github to the project or...?

Comment: @YanSoo I mean you can tell me how to reproduce the issue, so that we can help you faster